# Limiting the memory consumption of Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

Is there a way to limit the memory consumption of Python on Windows?

I'm running some experiments with TensorFlow 1.3.0, Python 3.6.3, Windows 7, all 64-bit. Problem: even a very small error in a TensorFlow program can cause runaway memory consumption. Unfortunately, Windows tries to use virtual memory to keep the program running, with the result that it goes so deep into disk thrashing that the machine locks up for several minutes.

I'd like to solve the problem by switching to 32-bit Python, but it seems TensorFlow only supports 64-bit.

Does any element of the stack provide a way to limit the memory consumption? Of course I'm not expecting a buggy program to work; what I want it to do once memory consumption exceeds a certain threshold is *crash*, so it doesn't go into disk thrashing and lock up the machine.

Comment: You can use a Job object to limit memory consumption. However, Windows 7 doesn't support nesting Job objects. You'll have to spawn a child process using the flag `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`. That should allow the child to break away, unless the Job doesn't allow child processes to break away. This is much easier to work with in Windows 8+ since a process can be associated with multiple Job objects.

Comment: The question is about main memory or GPU memory?

Comment: @Maxim Main memory.